# 2201B ERROR: invalid regular expression when using replace() function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Why Postgres gives me this error

> [2014-10-30 13:43:36] [2201B] ERROR: invalid regular expression:
>   invalid escape \ sequence   Where: PL/pgSQL function
>   normalize_username() line 5 at assignment

when I use the SQL statement:

```
UPDATE users."user" SET username = username
```

with the following trigger active:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION normalize_username()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $normalize_username$
BEGIN
  IF NOT (NEW.username IS NULL)
  THEN
    NEW.username := replace(NEW.username, 'ё', 'е');
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$normalize_username$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Table was created like this:

```
            CREATE TABLE USERS.user (
              user_id                SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
              username                CITEXT,
)
```

replace() is a simple text function, right? It shouldn't have any relation to regular expressions I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by casting username to TEXT in assignment like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION normalize_username()
  RETURNS TRIGGER AS $normalize_username$
BEGIN
  IF NOT (NEW.username IS NULL)
  THEN
    NEW.username := replace(NEW.username::TEXT, 'ё', 'е');
  END IF;
  RETURN NEW;
END;
$normalize_username$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It looks like CITEXT column operations are silently converted to regular expression operations under the hood. Can someone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue with postgres v13 function REPLACE(source, old_text, new_text ). Casting old_text to TEXT resolved the issue.